# How does client app re-authenticate user against doorkeeper auth server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, frontend, doorkeeper

Assume we have:

- auth-server (rails application using doorkeeper)
- client-app (react app, no server)
- resource-server (API built with rails)

Here's how I see the authorization flow working:

1. user clicks sign_in on client-app
2. client-app sends user to doorkeeper with these params:
   clinet_id
   redirect_uri
   response_type=token
3. after user authorizes app, auth server redirects back to client-app(to redirect url), access_token is part of that url, client-app saves access_token.
4. make request to resource-server with access_token to fetch resources.
5. resource-server makes request to auth-server with access_token, 
   gets current_user with that access_token.
6. resource-server responds with data based on current_user.

Now, access_token that client-app gets from auth-server only lives for 2 hours.

So after 2 hours, when client-app tries to make a request, resource server will try to fetch current_user but will get 401, and will respond to client-app with 401.

At this point, all client-app has is client_id and expired access_token.

**How does client-app obtain new access_token?**

I couldn't find much in doorkeeper wiki about this. It seems all examples and setup there require secret.

Comment: Maybe im not understanding this correctly but wouldnt the client have to re authorize with the oauth provider app? Either that or set the token to never expire and just delete the token from the server/session when you would like to log the user out.

Comment: @Verty00, thanks for the response. Setting taken to never expire is one way to go and that scenario is pretty clear to me. However, I understand best practices suggest to not do that but instead expire tokens in 2-4 hours.  Now, reauthenticating the user seems a logical thing to do, but would that require user to go to provider page again? or is it done behind the scene? I don't expect user to go to the provider page, that seems unreasonable. So the question is how exactly, using your words "client re-authorize with the oauth provider app"? I'm missing something, can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Hey. According to most oauth2 flows Ive set up ( mostly instagram and facebook auth ) whenever the user is logged out of the client app ( or has an expired token ) they will have to return to the provider for a new token. There is no way to avoid this. 

With providers such as facebook and instagram when this happens you are just automatically forwarded back to the client app if you happen to already be logged in to your provider ( instagram or facebook ).

Comment: However they wont have to re-authorize the providers app permissions. Only the first time they sign up do they have to agree to the requested permissions. Any sign up after that they should only need to enter login credentials.